# Spark - how to get all columns of the previous value using window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame with the schema look like this

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

and my window looks like

```
w = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("timestamp")
```

I would like to add a new column `calculation` to my data frame which requires doing some logic with column1, 2, 3 from both current row and the previous row in the window. Something like

```
df2 = df.withColumn(”calculation“, my_udf( currentCol1, currentCol2, currentCol3, lastCol1, lastCol2, lastCol3 ) )
```

`lag` only allows getting one column from previous row a time and I don't think applying window functions 3 times to get all 3 previous values are appropriate approach. Is there a way I can achieve getting the entire previous row? (getting all the columns)

Comment: I have a workaround for this,if that works for you. concatenate multiple columns inside lag and then within the udf you can split the column values and carry out the transformation. ```lag(concat_ws("|",col1,col2,col3)) over (windowSpec)```

Comment: what does your udf do to those column? can you give a sample of your data?

Answer (score 3):

To get all the previous rows, you can use `Window.unboundedPreceding` in the window frame.

```
w = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0) # 0 is the current row
```

But to apply an UDF to a window, I think you have the option to use the expensive `collect_list` function. Also you need to do it to every columns your UDF needs. For example :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0) # 0 is the current row

df = df.withColumn('result', your_udf(F.collect_list('col1').over(w).alias('a'), 
                                      F.collect_list('col2').over(w).alias('b')))
```

I don't know how your UDF works, so this might not work for you.

Comment: I am not actually asking for getting all the previous rows. My question was to get all the columns/fields of the previous row (1 row). I know I can achieve that by calling window function `lag` on every column, but isn't that bad for performance?

Comment: Oh I see. yeah I agree, I think there is no straightforward way except calling `lag` for every columns.